# How to make SVG act like Flexboxes

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, flexbox

In an `SVG` element, I need to make a layout that would be really easy to achieve with `flexboxes`:

```css
.box {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    fill: red;
    background-color: red;
}

.flex-container {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 15px;
    gap: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Obviously, it doesn't work *as is* with SVG:

```css
.box {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    fill: red;
    background-color: red;
}

.flex-container {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 15px;
    gap: 5px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="flex-container">
    <rect class="box" />
    <rect class="box" />
    <rect class="box" />
    <rect class="box" />
    <rect class="box" />
</svg>

<svg class="flex-container">
    <rect class="box" x="0" y="0" />
    <rect class="box" x="45" y="0" />
    <rect class="box" x="90" y="0" />
    <rect class="box" x="135" y="0" />
    <rect class="box" x="180" y="0" />
</svg>
```

The second one only *looks better* (yet not actually what I want) because I manually set the `x` and `y` properties.

In my real-life example, I don't know the number of boxes I have to place, hence I can't manually place them.

---

To be totally transparent, this is part of a React app (but it doesn't really matter as the markup generated remains the same):

```
import React from 'react';

const Svg = () => {
    const boxList = Array(5).fill({}); // This list is actually retrieved from an API call

    return (
        <svg className="flex-container">
            {boxList.map((box, idx) => (
                <rect key={idx} className="box" />
            ))}
        </svg>
    );
};

export default Svg;
```

Comment: SVG and Flexbox are two different world, no, two different universe. Don't try to make one work like the other. With SVG your are obliged to specify the position of each element manually

Comment: ..however, there are JS libraries that may be of help: https://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/02/02/svg-layout-flexbox.html